# Redefine \section to produce a second line within the section title

Tags: sectioning

I'm trying to redefine the `\section` command to produce a second line within the heading that is in a different style to the main heading. I want it to look something like the below image (except with section numbering).[image: section command result]

This was produced using the following code.

```
\textbf{\large Text}

\textit{\scriptsize\textcolor{gray}{Text}}
```

I've tried looking at the titlesec package but I'm not really sure.

Comment: Provive minimal working example with `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}`. No one should imagine your problem. Just minimal code.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you don't want the subtitle to show up in the table of contents and in the headers.

I suggest to define a `\Section` command with an optional argument where you can set things up. Since this uses the standard `\section` command, you can modify the style with `titlesec` or whatever method.

### The code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\Section}{sO{}m}
 {
  \keys_set:nn { bzirzer/section }
   {
    header=,toc=,subtitle=,#2
   }
  \bzirzer_section:nn { #1 } { #3 }
 }

\keys_define:nn { bzirzer/section }
 {
  header .tl_set:N = \l_bzirzer_section_header_tl,
  toc    .tl_set:N = \l_bzirzer_section_toc_tl,
  subtitle .tl_set:N = \l_bzirzer_section_subtitle_tl,
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \bzirzer_section:nn
 {
  \bool_if:nTF { #1 }
   {% unnumbered
    \section* { \__bzirzer_section_make:n { #2 } }
   }
   {% numbered
    \tl_if_empty:NTF \l_bzirzer_section_toc_tl
     {
      \section[ #2 ]{ \__bzirzer_section_make:n { #2 } }
     }
     {
      \section[ \l_bzirzer_section_toc_tl ]{ \__bzirzer_section_make:n { #2 } }
     }
    \tl_if_empty:NTF \l_bzirzer_section_header_tl
     {
      \sectionmark{#2}
     }
     {
      \sectionmark{\l_bzirzer_section_header_tl}
     }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__bzirzer_section_make:n
 {
  #1
  \tl_if_empty:NF \l_bzirzer_section_subtitle_tl
   { \\ {\normalfont\normalsize\itshape \tl_use:N \l_bzirzer_section_subtitle_tl} }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Title}

\Section*[subtitle=Where we present things]{Introduction}

\lipsum

\Section[subtitle=This is important]{Starting off}

\lipsum

\Section[
  subtitle=This is not important,
  toc=Abbreviated title for the toc,
  header=Abbreviated title for the header
]{This is a very long section title that should wrap across lines}

\lipsum\lipsum

\Section{This has no subtitle}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

### Some pictures.

#### 1. The unnumbered section

[image]

#### 2. A normal section with the subtitle

[image]

#### 3. A long section title with the subtitle

[image]

#### 4. Its abbreviated header

[image]

#### 5. The table of contents

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can put pretty much anything into a section title, but not the (optional) version sent to the TOC and `\sectionmark`.  Note, the line spacing is set for the paragraph as a whole, in this case using `\scriptsize`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section[short title]{\scriptsize\textbf{\large Text}\\
\textit{\textcolor{gray}{Text}}}

\end{document}
```